# Ionic hybrid application good for Banking Financial Project?

Tags: angular, security, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am planning to implement financial product based on Ionic hybrid application. But I read many article.So i get to know. Some glitch with security. But I am also believe on ionic is best framework for hybrid application. because we can use javascript framework like Anglar2/++, react. So should I got with ionic or not.

Here one line mentioned, Ionic is not good for financial product.
https://www.javatpoint.com/ionic-vs-phonegap

[image]

Comment: When it comes to hybrid frameworks and "secure" apps - ask yourself is a web-site context secure enough for you financial product? if the answer is "yes" then Ionic/Angular or whatever other javascript/webview based framework should be fine for you. See: TD Ameritrade Mobile